# Permission denied inside Docker container

Tags: docker

I have a started container `gigantic_booth` and I want to create the directory `/etc/test`:

```
# docker exec -it gigantic_booth /bin/bash
$ mkdir /etc/test
$ mkdir: cannot create directory '/etc/test': Permission denied
```

And `sudo` command is not found. I don't want to create this directory in image-build-time but once is started.

How can I do?

Thanks :)

Comment: An `id` command to see which user you are might help. `$` often dnotes nonpriv user.  Also - are you using `selinux`, and are there any relevant /var/log/messages entries? Are you mounting `/etc` from anywhere?

Comment: I'm using `jenkins` base image and I have just discovered this: http://superuser.com/questions/916918/jenkins-docker-image-has-no-make-or-sudo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or just use `docker exec -u thejenkinsuser`.

Answer (score 19):

I'm using `jenkins` image and I have just read that it has root access disabled for security reasons. https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker#installing-more-tools

I have re-built the image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins

USER root
```

and now it works properly, it is not so secure, though.

Comment: Or just `docker exec -u thejenkinsuser`