# "Permission denied" in Docker container unless --privileged=true

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, permissions, docker-compose

I'm trying to run an nginx container as a service and share 2 volumes between the host machine and container, so that files in one directory are automatically shared with the other paired directory.

My docker-compose.yml is the following:

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:80"
    volumes:
     - /home/user1/share:/share/user1
     - /home/user2/share:/share/user2
    restart: always
```

The only way I can get this to work currently is by adding `privileged: true` to the docker-compose file, however I am not allowed to due this due to security requirements.

When trying to access the volume in the container, I get the following error:

```
[root@host docker-nginx]# docker exec -it dockernginx_nginx_1 bash
root@2d574f9c6131:/# ls /share/user1/
ls: cannot open directory /share/user1/: Permission denied
```

Even attaching myself to bash on the container with the following parameters denies me of accessing the resource (or at least listing the contents):
`docker exec -it --privileged=true -u 6004:6004 dockernginx_nginx_1 bash`
(Note: `6004:6004` happens to be the id:gid ownership that is passed on to `/share/user1/`)

Is there any way of accessing the contents without building the `nginx service` with elevated privileges?

Perhaps the issue lies in SELinux restrictions enforced in the container?
The container is running `Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)` and the host is running `CentOS Linux 7 (Core)`

Related questions:

- [Permission denied inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902663/permission-denied-inside-docker-container)

Comment: I believe it is related to SELinux, because that is one of the things that changes with the `privileged` flag.

Comment: @dnephin You are correct, I had two leads which was either because I'm running an old Docker version or permissions with SELinux. It turns out it was SELinux, the daemon ran with `--selinux-enabled=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker was running with `--selinux-enabled=true`, this prohibited me from accessing the contents of directories in the container.
Read more: http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/07/docker-selinux-flag/

The solution was to disable it, it can either be done by (1) configuring or by (2) installing the non-selinux CentOS package, I went with option 2:

I made sure to reinstall and update Docker from 1.10 to 1.12.1 and not install `docker-engine-selinux.noarch` but instead have `docker-engine.x86_64` and have the SELinux package installed as a dependency (yum does this automatically). By doing this and starting the Docker daemon, you can verify with `ps aux | grep "docker"` that `docker-containerd` is not started with the `--selinux-enabled=true` option.